# flutter call a function after moving back to screen from another screen

Tags: flutter

How to call a function in flutter ,after moving back to a screen from another screen?

For Example:

Screen 1

```
function1(){
}
```

Screen2

```
function2(){
//Go back to screen 1 and then call function1()
}
```

Comment: check what `Navigator.push*()` methods return

Comment: It's not about returning data from screen. It's about call a function of another screen

Comment: `Navigator.push*()` methods return a `Future` so if you use `Future` API you will know when the "another screen" called `Navigator.pop()` method, you dont know how to use `Future` API to be called when `Future` completes?

Answer (score 4):

It's simple.

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> SecondScreen())).then((_){
      // This method gets callback after your SecondScreen is popped from the stack or finished.
      function1();
    });
```

You should also refer the [Flutter Navigation & Routing.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution!

**Second Screen**

```
Navigator.pop(context, [1]);
```

or, if you don't want to send back any data, you can only call

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

**First Screen**

```
Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => SecondScreen(), ), ).then((value) { //do something after resuming screen
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho the solutions provided here aren't valid solutions.
If you use a routes Future it may be called multiple times and will even be called in case of a forward navigation.

Instead use a NavigatorObserver:

```
class AppNavigationObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print("AppNavigationObserver: ${route.settings.name}");
    print("AppNavigationObserver: ${previousRoute?.settings.name}");
  }
}
```

You can then use it for example like this:

```
  MaterialApp(
    navigatorObservers: [
      AppNavigationObserver()
    ],
    onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
      return PageRouteBuilder(
        maintainState: true,
        settings: settings,
        transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
          // Your route builder according to settings
        },
      );
    },
  )
```

The important part is passing onGenerateRoute's settings paramter to the PageRouteBuilder settings. Otherwise settings.arguments and settings.name will be null in the didPop handler.